# How to handle page hang using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

While automating a test-case, sometimes I come across a situation where page simply hang-up due to various factors.

How to declare the particular Test-case as fails and move on to the next test-cases?

I am using java to write script in selenium webdriver.

Comment: Are tests not failing due to NoSuchElement exception?

Comment: @Manu situation like slow network leading to page hangup.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in which page hangup will affect the automated tests.

1. Selenium will wait for page to load.
2. Selenium will wait for element to load.

In first case, you can use `pageLoadTimeout` which will wait for the given time and throws the exception if page do not load. Just

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

In second case, the test should fail by itself throwing the `NoSuchElementException`. You can handle the exceptions to fail the tests and move to the next one.